# Icon and splash screen doesn't apply

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

According to guides from Ionic docs, I created two .png files(icon(192x192) and splash(2208x2208)) and put them in the  **resources** folder. Then I ran  *`ionic resources`* , so default images were replaced. But somehow, it didn't make any impact. Furthermore, as I understood, default images haven't applied before - I had, and still have grey cordova launch icon and white splash screen. My configuration:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.2
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.18
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.9
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.44
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Linux 4.4
Node Version: v7.4.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

I'm running application on Android device, and as I checked resources in platforms/android/res weren't changed. Just replacing files do the trick but this is not the best solution from my point of view :)

Comment: Are you trying in a device? also can you add the output of `ionic resources` to the question?

Comment: What platform do you face the issue on?

Comment: Try re-adding your platform using ; ionic platform add|remove android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the icon of an ionic application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41895252/how-to-change-the-icon-of-an-ionic-application)

Answer (score 0):

Update your project to Cordova 6.5.0 using following commands.

```
npm install -g cordova
```

If you already have the project built using cordova earlier version you have to update the android platform of your project.

```
cordova platform update android@6.1.1
```

Hope this will fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have saved both new images with name icon.png and splash.png

better you use separate commands to install both

Like

ionic resources --icon and

ionic resources --splash

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for your White SplashScreen problem.
With the last version of Ionic, you need to verify a line in your config.xml file :

Make sure you have the line :
`<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>`

Instead of :
`<preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash"/>`

You need to have the value `"screen"` here and not the old version which is `"splash"` !!!

Now my SplashScreen is not white anymore and it takes my resources files generated from PSD file.

And here is my Ionic Info prompt :

`Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.0.0
ios-deploy version: 1.9.1
ios-sim version: 5.0.13
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.9.5
Xcode version: Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002`